# bash непонятное поведения if-then

Tags: linux, bash

Есть код:

```
if [[ ! -f file1 ]];
 then
  echo "0" > /tmp/file1;
  echo "check 1";
fi;
```

При запуске скрипта печатается:

> check 1

При проверке условия:

```
[[ ! -f file1 ]]
echo $?
```

В консоль печатается 0.
Но раз условие 0, то блок then не должен срабатывать? Почему он срабатывает?

Comment: лишние `;` убрать стоит, это же не С/C++

Comment: удаление ; не помогло

Comment: И да, 0 - это статус успешного завершения, то бишь условие истинно.

Comment: И вообще лучше писать проще и без башизмов: `[ -f file1 ] || echo “0” > /tmp/file1`.